# Restarting pulse audio deamon from crontab

Tags: cron, pulseaudio

I'd like to restart the pulseaudio deamon from cron overnight.   Audio mic seems garbled when I start my morning meetings, but is fine after a restart.

I have the following cron entry

```bash
* * * * * bash -c "pulseaudio -k" > ~/log/pulseaudio_restart.crontab.log 2>&1
```

but it's unable to find the pulse audio deamon:

```
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Impossible de tuer le démon : Aucun processus de ce type
```

which means: `Impossible to kill daemon: no process of that type`

In `/etc/init.d`, the only `pulseaudio` related script I see is `/etc/init.d/pulseaudio-enable-autospawn`.

So how do I restart the pulseaudio daemon from cron?